# Add fog or mist or dust to an animation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation

Is there a way to add fog - mist -dust or any other effect like glare etc to an already rendered animation in blender cycles?

Many Thanks

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload reference images of what you want to achieve. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: You can do fog in post in the compositor, but that animation would have to be rendered with either a Z pass or a Mist pass or both. Try this tutorial see if it helps: https://blenderartists.org/t/quick-tip-z-depth-or-mist-pass/598640 .